# Is is possible to use <a title="<a>">

Tags: javascript, href, photo, title, viewer

I am creating a site with some pictures on it of me and my friends. To be able to view those photos quickly I've added the Milkbox javascript to my site ([Milkbox Site](http://reghellin.com/milkbox/)). You can add photo's like this:

```
<a href="img01.png" data-milkbox="albumsorting" title="Photo description goes here."><img src="thumbs/thumbimg01.png" /></a>
```

In the title I want to add a download link for the photo. This should look like this:

```
<a href="img01.png" data-milkbox="albumsorting" title="<a href="img01.png">Download photo</a> | Photo description goes here."><img src="thumbs/thumbimg01.png /></a>
```

Does anyone have any experience using Milkbox and this way (or another) of adding Download links to the description?

Comment: You cannot put any markup in ordinary (browser-native) title text.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to get this working? It's probably Milkbox that does not support other make-up of your html code, right..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Milbox does support it and it's even in the doc.

use html entities to convert your text - in your case '<a href="img01.png">Download photo</a>`:

```
<a href="img01.png" data-milkbox="albumsorting" title="&lt;a href=&quot;img01.png&quot;&gt;Download photo&lt;/a&gt;  | Photo description goes here."><img src="thumbs/thumbimg01.png /></a>
```

Comment: Sweet! This is the fix! Thanks alot for the help :D

Comment: I need to wait a few more seconds before I can mark your answer ;) Been spamming it :p

Answer (score 0):

No. All attributes exept `alt` only accept plain text.

However, you can achieve your goal with custom tooltips from a javascript library like [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap).

`alt` serves as a way for old browsers to show content when the original isn't compatible.

Example:

```
<div alt="<div> your browser cannot display the content"> <intricate content/></div>
```

**EDIT:** Milkbox offers support fort this.